# MX Record for all heroku review apps

Tags: email, heroku, dns

I want to set up heroku and my MX records such that whenever I spin up a review app, eMail can already be routed to it.

For example, if I create a new review app and heroku assigns it the name:

```
company-feature-email-123abc.staging.example.com
```

I want there to already be be a wildcard MX record in my zone file to successfully route eMail to that review app.

What's the right way to phrase this MX record?

Comment: Put a `MX` record on `*.staging.company.com` if I understood you correctly, but your question is offtopic here.

Comment: I have to push back on the "this is off topic" comment: This forum is where heroku routes all heroku-specific questions. This is a heroku-specific question.

Comment: Creating a MX record in the DNS is not a programming task... Except if you do it with a program, which is not the question here as your question is really just "how to configure the DNS to do X", and whatever X you put there, heroku or not, is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard MX record would look like this in a DNS zone file:

```
*.example.com.    IN      MX      10 <mail-server-name>
```

Make sure to read [RFC 1912 section 2.7: Wildcard records](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912#section-2.7). Here's part of it:

> Wildcard MXs are useful mostly for non IP-connected sites.  A common
> mistake is thinking that a wildcard MX for a zone will apply to all
> hosts in the zone.  A wildcard MX will apply only to names in the
> zone which aren't listed in the DNS at all.  e.g.,

> ```
>        podunk.xx.      IN      NS      ns1
> ```

```
                       IN      NS      ns2
       mary            IN      A       1.2.3.4
       *.podunk.xx.    IN      MX      5 sue
```

> Mail for mary.podunk.xx will be sent to itself for delivery.  Only
> mail for jane.podunk.xx or any hosts you don't see above will be sent
> to the MX.  For most Internet sites, wildcard MX records are not
> useful.  You need to put explicit MX records on every host.

See also this answer to a similar question on server fault:
https://serverfault.com/a/405640/494284